# ODBCDataReader.Read() performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

I have an application that is reading data from a database using an ODBCDataReader. The `ODBCDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader()` line executes very quickly, but the first iteration of rdr.Read() takes an incredibly long (15 or more seconds) to process. Each successive iteration is substantially faster (less than a second.)

There are relatively few rows being returned (<100), but there are about 170 columns in each row.

I'm confused as to why this only occurs on the first pass through the .Read() command. Basically, I'm porting data from one database into another, and build an insert query for each record returned by the data reader. Is there something being done behind the scenes when the datareader first reads, and is there any way around this problem? This import should take only a minute or two, and is taking hours because of this problem! The relevant code follows, but is likely not going to be helpful for troubleshooting this issue:

```
    OdbcDataReader odbcRdr = odbcCom.ExecuteReader();
    while (odbcRdr.Read())
    {
         //Process the record and insert into the new database.
    }
```

As I said, once it gets past the first iteration of odbcRdr.Read(), the code flys and inserts all the records in less than a second.

Comment: Have you executed the query in the dbms? Does it take the same time to start streaming the records? Can you show us the sql?

Comment: The SQL is pretty straightforward as well. `SELECT * FROM root.dagent WHERE row_date >= '<some date>' AND row_date >= '<another date>' AND logid = <some login id>`. In the dbms I do not have any problems executing this statement.

Comment: The same if you use a `OdbcDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`? It uses also a `DataReader` under the hood, just out of curiosity. Do you need all 170 columns?

Comment: I've not used a `DataTable` yet, because I presumed the user of `DataReader` behind the scenes would provide the same problem. And sadly I do need all 170 columns. I'm thinking that is what's causing the problem, but I haven't had a good way to test this theory as I don't have any other 2+million record tables with 150+ columns available :)

Comment: You could try to use the overload of [`ExecuteReader`](http://tinyurl.com/cvkfm8h) with a `Commandbehaviour`. `SequentialAccess`: "provides a way for the DataReader to handle rows that contain columns with large binary values. Rather than loading the entire row, SequentialAccess enables the DataReader to load data as a stream. You can then use the GetBytes or GetChars method to specify a byte location to start the read operation, and a limited buffer size for the data being returned.
When you specify SequentialAccess, you are required to read from the columns in the order they are returned".

Comment: Using `SequentialAccess` has also not increased performance. The DataReader still loads the data the same way, it just changes the way the data can be accessed, as best I can tell. My assumption here is that on the first `.Read()`, the actual data structure for the reader is being created for each of the 170 rows. Each subsequent pass is just mapping the next row to the structure created in the initial pass. I'm beginning to think there is not going to be a way around this, aside from returning fewer columns.